# Can't produce mesh using CreateGroundFromHeightMap function. Getting ground object in alert popup reports it has 0 subdivisions and 0 vertices

Tags: babylonjs, heightmap

So, I've just picked up BabylonJS and having rendered some basic shapes, I read about the CreateGroundFromHeightMap function and thought I'd give it a go. However, I've been unsuccessful in getting a mesh render in my scene and I can't see anything that obviously explains why what's going wrong. My scene code is as follows:

```js
const createScene =  () => {
          const scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
          const camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera("camera", -Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2.5, 3, new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
          camera.attachControl(canvas, true);
          const light = new BABYLON.HemisphericLight("light", new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 1, 0));
          var groundMaterial = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("ground", scene);
          var ground = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateGroundFromHeightMap("ground", "heightmap.jpg", 200, 200, 20, 0, 10, scene);
          ground.material = groundMaterial;
          return scene;
      };
```

As far as I can tell, I've followed the examples I've seen online and I've confirmed that my image path is valid, but all I get is an empty scene and there are no browser console errors, so I can't really tell what's going wrong. As I said in my question title, I tried passing my ground variable to an alert popup and got this result, clearly indicating that it's not generating the mesh successfully: "Name: ground, isInstance: YES, # of submeshes: 0, n vertices: 0, parent: NONE". Any ideas what might be going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so in case this is useful to anyone else, I got it working. First, I used BABYLON.MeshBuilder instead of of BABYLON.Mesh. Also, I was unaware that I couldn't just point the function to a local image file path, which I've discovered appears to be the case upon trying a heightmap image from a web URL and finding that it worked. Following this discovery, I tried setting up my scene with all my files on an Apache web server instead and it now works!